# entry point for apache torque project

Tags: java, jsp, jboss, xdoclet, apache-torque

I've a project that contains `webroot` folder name war and contains a structure like

[image]

but it doesn't contains a `web.xml` like other common entry point for web projects.How i start this torque project?What is the entry point for torques web project?
my another question is here `xdoclet` folder in my structure contains a folder name `merge` that contains some `servlet mapping` files.so what is connection of `xdoclect` and mapping of servlet.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you will find answers to your questions looking at build.xml. Probably you need to build your project (both descriptors and xdoclet work will be done by ANT).

In order to do that, a good starting point could be:

- where you've downloaded this project structure
- open a shell, go into the directory where there's build.xml and type

  ant --projecthelp

I assume ant is in your PATH. Otherwise you can prefix the ant command with the whole path of the ant command.